# Migrating content down a level in wagtail streamfield

Tags: django, wagtail, django-migrations, wagtail-streamfield

I've got a wagtail page model with an existing streamfield. The streamfield has now changed format and I'd like the text content to migrated down a level into a streamblock.

The initial model (simplified):

```
class ProjectPage(Page):
    description = StreamField(
        [
            ("text", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
            ("image", ImageBlock()),
        ]
    )
```

The new model (also simplified):

```
class ProjectPage(Page):
    description = StreamField(
        [
            (
                "section",
                blocks.StreamBlock(
                    [
                        ("text", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
                        ("image", ImageBlock()),
                    ]
                ),
            )
        ],
    )
```

Currently, the `image` blocks are empty, so only the `text` item needs migrating.

I tried looping through pages and doing `old_data = page.description.raw_data` then using that to make the new content `[{'type': 'section', 'value': old_data}]`.

If I `page.save()` and get the value for `page.description.raw_data`, I see the new content, but the admin still shows the old values.

I'm guessing this is linked to revisions vs published versions but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Any pointers would be welcome!